# Tensor product of complex function field over complex or real field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $\mathbb{C}$ and $R$ be complex and real number fields. Let $C(x)$ and $C(y)$ be function fields of one variable. Consider $\mathbb{C}(x) ⊗_R \mathbb{C}(y)$ and $\mathbb{C}(x) ⊗_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}(y)$.  
(1). Determine if they are integral domains. 
(2). Determine if they are fields.

I have learned finite seperable field extension tensor product over field. But clearly they are both infinite dimensional. And for the second tensor, I know they are linearly disjoint over $\mathbb{C}$ but $x,y$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$

For $\mathbb{C}(x) ⊗_R \mathbb{C}(y)$, I don't have any idea. Maybe let $\mathbb{C}(x)=\mathbb{R}(i,x)$?  But how to show its structure?